# Data attribute for bulletlist in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET BulletedList, when I add List Items to it, it just displays there text in the markup, so I am not able to get the value of listitem using JS or JQuery.

Is there anyway I could add any data attribute to bulletlist, so that I could get it back when needed ?

Not able to find any related property here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property inherited from WebControl should allow you to add any attribute you want.

```
ListItem listitem = new ListItem("text", "value");
listitem.Attributes.Add("data-value", "value");
listCtrl.Items.Add(listitem);
```